# Eliminating duplicates from a list and copying result into separate worksheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I am here because I need help with the task stated above. At my student worker job we have a list of customers in a column of a spreadsheet that we add to whenever we take in job orders. What I need help with is basically transferring over a weeded out version (no duplicates) of this list into a different spreadsheet with a total number of entries.

My boss gave me this job because I was messing around with other aspects of VBA code in my spare time and he noticed. Unfortunately, I'm not entirely 100% sure how to do this since I'm pretty new to the language.

Here is what I have so far (note it doesn't work)
http://pastebin.com/E3bKbr24

Any help would be greatly appreciated and especially pointers on how to make this more efficient! I know C++ and I know that the double nested For loop is very inefficient so any suggested ways to improve the performance of this function would be helpful (especially since it will be called a lot).

Thanks again!

Comment: `What I need help with is basically transferring over a weeded out version (no duplicates) of this list into a different spreadsheet with a total number of entries.` PIVOT TABLE! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

```
Sub Copy()

    Worksheets("originalsheet").Columns("Q:Q").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("newsheet").Columns("Q:Q")
    Worksheets("newsheet").Columns("Q:Q").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Replace "originalsheet" with the name of the worksheet you're trying to copy data from, and replace "newsheet" with the name of the new worksheet you're trying to copy the data into. You can also replace the Qs in the columns for a broader range, like "C:S" if that's what you need.

If you want to keep everything in a same worksheet and re-use that one for what you need, it's better to create one externally than to create a new one in the sub, otherwise you'll end up with a new sheet each time you start the sub.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark your answer! This code works perfectly and is exactly what I needed. Now I start experimenting with it for other purposes. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has an inbuilt remove duplicates function (Data / Remove duplicates)

You can use it programmatically like so (Very basic example but should give you the hints to incorporate into your code):

```
Sub CopyUnique()
    Columns("Q:Q").Copy 'Copy column Q
    Workbooks.Add 'Add a workbook
    ActiveSheet.Paste ' Paste
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes 'remove dupes
End Sub
```

Comment: But if I want to add it to a specific worksheet that I've already built how would I go about referencing that worksheet? Workbooks.Add would create an entirely new file wouldn't it?

Comment: Before you add the workbook have `OB = Activeworkbook` You will need to Dim it as a workbook then instead of workbooks.add have `NB = Workbooks.add` OB is Old book and NB is New book, you can reference them as `OB.Range blah blah` or `OB.Activate`. Dim NB as a workbook too.

Comment: Your answers are extremely close to what I need but they don't quite solve the entirety of my issues. This code definitely copies all of the values and removes any duplicates (which was half of my problem) and it does move all of the values to a new workbook (I changed it to a new worksheet), but it doesn't move the values into the SAME worksheet each time. That is what I was trying to say before is that I need some way of referencing the same sheet each time (by name or something) to copy over the customer data.

Comment: Copy all the columns you want and remove dupes on the whole range, it doesn't have to just be 1 column :)